# If tr has td[rowspan]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am getting some data from a table and most of the data I need is in `$('tbody td:nth-child(1)')`

But some table rows have a td:nth-child(1) I need to skip, these are easily spotted because they have a rowspan, so if I see that I can skip it.

How can I get `$('tbody td:nth-child(1)')` but check if `$('tbody td:nth-child(1)')` has `$('td[rowspan]')`? If it does skip it and get the next td instead?

```
$(this).find('td:nth-child(1):not(tr[rowspan])')
```

The above does not work because it just will skip it entirely, I still need that data but need adapt to that particular case.

Comment: I think the adjacency selected can help http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html%23id-selectors#adjacent-selectors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to find all `tr` then find the first td which is not `[rowpsan]` so

```
$('tbody tr').find('td:not([rowspan]):first')
```

Comment: I am using cherrio though, it looks like it does not support :first selector, is there an alternate way to call first? Cherrio is a backend node.js jquery, I am scraping data

Comment: .find('td:not([rowspan]):nth-child(1)');